# how to return an arrays instead of an object using Laravel Api Resources

Tags: php, json, laravel

I was required to return this json, I am using api resources in Laravel:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "users",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "test name",
        "lastname": "test lastname"
        "projects": 2
      },
      "relationships": {
        "projects": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "type": "projects"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

A user has a first Project, I am doing this:

Models/User.php

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];      

    public function firstProject()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Project::class)->oldest();
    }

    public function projects()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }

}
```

ProjectCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class ProjectCollection extends ResourceCollection
{ 
    public function toArray($request)
    {         
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection
        ];
    }  
}
```

ProjectResource.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProjectResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "type" => "projects",
            "id" => $this->id               
        ];
    }
}
```

UserCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class UserCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection
        ];
    }          
}
```

UserResource.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        
        return [
            "type" => "users",
            "id" => $this->id,
            "attributes" => [
                "name" => $this->name,
                "lastname" => $this->lastname
                "projects" => $this->whenCounted('projects')
            ],
            "relationships" => [
                "projects" => new ProjectCollection($this->firstProject),
            ]            
        ];
    }
}
```

UsersController.php

```
    $users = User::with('firstProject')->withCount('projects')->latest()->limit(10)->get();

    return new UserCollection($users);
```

If I do this:

```
"relationships" => [
   "projects" => new ProjectCollection($this->firstProject),
 ]
```

I get this error:

> Call to undefined method App\Models\Project::mapInto()

But if I change it to this:

```
"relationships" => [
   "projects" => $this->firstProject,
]
```

It doesn't display errors, but I get this json:

```
...
...
"relationships": {
   "projects": 
       {
          "id": 1,
          "type": "projects"
       }
}
...
...
```

The projects is not wrapped in a **data** attribute y is not displaying the **[]**

What can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just neeed to wrap the $this->firstProject in an array

```
"relationships" => [
   "projects" => new ProjectCollection([$this->firstProject]),
]
```

and now it is wrapping it as an array in a **data** attribute despite I have only one item

```
"relationships": {
        "projects": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "type": "projects"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

This is the behaviour I wanted, now everything is fine